# Django modify image before it's handled by stdimage

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-stdimage for creating variations of the image.

```py
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = StdImageField(upload_to='photos', verbose_name=_("photo"),
                      variations={'large': (600, 600), 'thumbnail': (100, 100)}
```

`StdImageField` does it's own operations on the image, subclassing `ImageField` and having `attr_class = StdImageFieldFile`

`StdImageFieldFile` does the actual save operation

```py
class StdImageFieldFile(ImageFieldFile):
    """
    Like ImageFieldFile but handles variations.
    """

    def save(self, name, content, save=True):
        super(StdImageFieldFile, self).save(name, content, save)
        render_variations = self.field.render_variations
        if callable(render_variations):
            render_variations = render_variations(
                file_name=self.name,
                variations=self.field.variations,
                storage=self.storage,
            )
        if not isinstance(render_variations, bool):
            msg = (
                '"render_variations" callable expects a boolean return value,'
                ' but got %s'
                ) % type(render_variations)
            raise TypeError(msg)
        if render_variations:
            self.render_variations()
```

However, I want to do some manipulation of the image before StdImageFieldFile does it (rotating).

So I created my custom field, to catch the image before it's passed to stdimage

```py
class Rotate(ImageFieldFile):
    def save(self, name, content, save=True):
        save = False

        return super(Rotate, self).save(name, content, save)

class StdImageFieldFileRotateMixin(Rotate, StdImageFieldFile):
    pass

class StdImageFieldRotate(StdImageField):
    attr_class = StdImageFieldFileRotateMixin
```

I have the image in the `content` property of the `Rotate` class and I can manipulate the image using PIL, but after it's done, I don't know how to assign this image back to the content property. It seems that it's generated on the lower level. Is there a method to generate this `content` property and then MRO will handle the rest (i.e. pass it to StdImageFieldFile and it will do the rest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a callable to the argument `render_variations` of the `StdImageField` class and pre-process the image there.

For example assume you want to save disk space and resize the original image to a smaller version, taking only the smaller image together with variations created by django-stdimage. You can write a function like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

from stdimage.utils import render_variations

def preprocess(file_name, variations, storage):
    with storage.open(file_name) as f:
        with Image.open(f) as image:
            file_format = image.format

            # resize to a maximum of 1000x1000 keeping aspect ratio
            image.thumbnail((1000, 1000), resample=Image.ANTIALIAS)

            with BytesIO() as file_buffer:
                image.save(file_buffer, file_format)
                f = ContentFile(file_buffer.getvalue())
                # delete the original big image
                storage.delete(file_name)
                # save the resized version with the same filename and format
                storage.save(file_name, f)

    # render stdimage variations
    render_variations(file_name, variations, replace=True, storage=storage)

    return False  # prevent default rendering
```

You can then pass the function to the `render_variations` argument of the `StdImageField` class, like this:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = StdImageField(upload_to='photos', verbose_name=_("photo"),
                  variations={'large': (600, 600), 'thumbnail': (100, 100)},
                  render_variations=preprocess)
```

This technique is inspired from the [Async image processing example](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage) in the README of the django-stdimage project on Github.

Also the way in which the image is handled in the `preprocess` function is inspired from the [stdimage.models.StdImageFieldFile.render_variation](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage/blob/2.0.6/stdimage/models.py#L62) method and uses Django Storage objects to deal with different storage types for image files (think Amazon S3).